# How to stop screen from turning black on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management

I have a problem that on Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop.
After some minutes of no mouse movement and keystrokes the screen turns black and only turns back on when I close the lid and reopen it. For this I also have to log back in.

I made the following settings to stop this, but the problem persists:

1. Privacy > Screen lock. Blank Screen Delay: Never, Automatic Screen Lock: Off
2. Power: Dim screen when inactive: Off, Blank Screen: Never, Automatic Suspend: Off

I also installed and activated Caffeine, but the problem persists.

How can I stop screen from turning black? I'm using a "Dell XPS 17 (9710)" laptop.

edit: It was only after posting the question that I realised that the problem occurs only when I'm using the software "PyCharm". If any other window (like Terminal or Firefox) is focused, then the screen does not turn black. Even if PyCharm is running in the background.

Comment: Is `xset -dpms` helping?

Comment: Does your Dell XPS 17 have an NVidia card?  Some do, but not all of them do.  If so, have you tried installing updated NVidia drivers?

Comment: @nobody xset -dpms didn't help, unfortunately

Comment: @Ray Yes, my Dell XPS 17 has an NVidia card. After your suggestion, I tried installing nvidia-driver-510 (that seemed to be the latest tested proprietory driver), but the problem persists.

Comment: [This says it's for Ubuntu Server](https://linux-tips.us/how-to-disable-sleep-and-hibernation-on-ubuntu-server/) but it should work for a desktop system just fine. Have you tried that route?

Comment: You can find a more up to date NVidia driver on NVidia's web site [here](https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx).  Given that you're on 20.04, maybe the NVidia site will have a slightly more recent driver.  It's worth a shot.  Seems like your problem is with the screen saver not returning?  You could turn off the screen saver, but I don't think that's a very good long term solution.  Good luck with it!  My XPS 17 is being repaired...when it is fixed, I might have your problem...  We'll see!

Comment: I tried the two last solutions and nothing changed. But I realised that the problem only occurs when I'm using the program "PyCharm". So, my question is probably really a PyCharm question and not an Ubuntu question... I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: I've since uninstalled Ubuntu and use Kubuntu instead, where I don't have that problem. I never solved the original problem and now have no way to try new proposed solutions.

Comment: This problem shows up when watching a YouTube rented movie. I've been using Ubuntu for 10 years and it was never solved... unbelievable. The [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-blank.html.en) are also useless. "Screen Blank=Never" option does nothing. Just amazing.

Answer (score -1):

Following worked for me. ( I have NVidia gpu)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa 
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

did not need to restart.